# Pact with Jersey error handling

Tags: java, junit, jersey, grizzly, pact

I have created this awesome controller point:

```
@Named
@Path("/awsome")
@Api(value = "An Awsome api")
public class AwsomeEndpoint extends BaseEndpoint {

  @GET
  @Path("{isThisAwsome}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @ApiOperation(value = "Get organisation by isthisAwsome",
                notes = "Get AwsomeAnswer matching the given isThisAwsome.",
                responseContainer = "single result",
                response = JsonOrganisation.class)
  @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Awsome found"),
                         @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Awsome not found"),
                         @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Error")})
  public Response getAwsomeResponse(@PathParam("isThisAwsome") String isThisAwsome) {
    Response response = handleErrors(() -> Response.ok(AwsomeResponseTransformer.transform(awsomeService.getAwsomeByisThisAwsome(isThisAwsome))).build());
    return response;
  }
}
```

This code uses a Lamda to handle the error flow:

```
public class BaseEndpoint {

  protected Response handleErrors(Supplier<Response> responseSupplier) {
    Response response;
    try {
      response = responseSupplier.get();
    } catch (AwsomeRuntimeException e) {
      response = createExceptionResponse(e);
    }
    return response;
  }

  private Response createExceptionResponse(AwsomeRuntimeException e) {
    Response.ResponseBuilder response;

    if (e.getExceptionStatus() == ExceptionStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
      response = Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(e.getMessage());
    } else if (e.getExceptionStatus() == ExceptionStatus.ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT) {
      response = Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(e.getMessage());
    } else {
      response = Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e.getMessage());
    }

    return response.header("","").header("Pragma", "no-cache, no-store").header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store").header("Expires", "0").build();
  }}
```

For this I created some Pact test, all pacts work except when we i mock an error being thrown by the service we call.

An example of the pact test class:

```
RunWith(PactRunner.class)
@Provider("awsome")
@PactBroker(authentication=@PactBrokerAuth(username = "${pact.broker.username:x}", password = "${pact.broker.password:x}"),
            protocol="${pact.broker.protocol:https}", host="${pact.broker.host:hosted.pact.dius.com.au}", port="${pact.broker.port:443}",
            failIfNoPactsFound=false)
public class AccMgtPactIntegrationTest extends JerseyTest {

  @TestTarget public final HttpTarget target = new HttpTarget(getPort());
  private AwsomeService awsomeService;
  private UserService         userService;

  @Override
  protected ResourceConfig configure() {
    awsomeService = mock(AwsomeService.class);
    return new ResourceConfig().register(new OrganisationsEndpoint(awsomeService)).register(new AwsomeEndpoint())
        //                               .property(ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, "true")
        ;
  }

  @State("Notn found")
  public void whenOrganisationWithShortNameDoesNotExist() {
    when(awsomeService.getOrganisationByShortName("WME")).thenThrow(new AwsomeRuntimeException(ExceptionStatus.NOT_FOUND));
  } }
```

Now I get some weard errors from Pact, and I think its not pact thats the problem but how girlzy works in pact. Becoue I get the folowing error:

```
 Verifying a pact between consumer and aswsome   Given when
 organisation with shortName does not exist   Get awsome by isItAwsome
     returns a response which
       has status code 404 (OK)
       includes headers
         "Content-Type" with value "application/json" (FAILED)
       has a matching body (FAILED)
```

> > Failures:
>
> 0) Get organisation by short name returns a response which includes
>   headers "Content-Type" with value "application/json"
>         Expected header 'Content-Type' to have value 'application/json' but was 'text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1'
>
> 1) Get organisation by short name returns a response which has a
>   matching body
>         comparison -> Expected a response type of 'application/json' but the actual type was 'text/html'

Now if I set the (commented out propertie) `RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR`

Then pact fails like this:

```
Verifying a pact between consumer and aswsome
  Given when organisation with shortName does not exist
  Get awsome by isItAwsome:
ul 13, 2017 12:54:14 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler doServletService
SEVERE: service exception:
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.FilterChainImpl.invokeFilterChain(FilterChainImpl.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.doServletService(ServletHandler.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.service(ServletHandler.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:147)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpHeader.isSpecialHeader(HttpHeader.java:925)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpHeader.handleGetSpecialHeader(HttpHeader.java:901)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpHeader.containsHeader(HttpHeader.java:762)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Response.containsHeader(Response.java:1268)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.HttpServletResponseImpl.containsHeader(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:472)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.writeResponseStatusAndHeaders(ResponseWriter.java:159)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:683)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:434)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    ... 12 more

    returns a response which
      has status code 404 (FAILED)
      includes headers
        "Content-Type" with value "application/json" (FAILED)
      has a matching body (FAILED)
```

> > Failures:

```
0) Get organisation by short name returns a response which includes headers "Content-Type" with value "application/json"
      Expected header 'Content-Type' to have value 'application/json' but was 'text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1'

1) Get organisation by short name returns a response which has a matching body
      comparison -> Expected a response type of 'application/json' but the actual type was 'text/html'

2) Get organisation by short name returns a response which has status code 

    404
          assert expectedStatus == actualStatus
                 |              |  |
                 404            |  500
                                false
```

I have the feeling that grizly does not like the Lamda I made for the error handling. But I do not want to change my code just so that I can make my provider work because of he server container. Any ideas I have been trying to debug the code and it flows correctly till it hands it over to the container. And then it seems to ignore the Jersy annotations completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, the fix feels dirty but it worked. It seems that the grizley container doesnt realy load whole jersy. So in the end I ended up putting the JSON response in my mock like this:

```
when(awsomeService.getOrganisationByShortName("WME")).thenThrow(new AwsomeRuntimeException(ExceptionStatus.NOT_FOUND,"{\n"
        + "    \"timestamp\": 1500040460362,\n" + "    \"status\": 404,\n" + "    \"error\": \"Not Found\",\n" + "    \"message\": \"Not Found\",\n"
        + "    \"path\": \"/awsome/isThisAwsome/ABCDE\"\n" + "}"));
```

Pact seems happy its getting somting like a JSON response it can map to. And I dont have to load more Jersy then I want in the test container. (Witch I coudent figure out).

So all in all this works it doesnt feel fully the richt way but its for a non standard flow so I am ok with it for now.

Answer (score 1):

I think your mock isn't setup correctly and that's why you're not handling the right exception. Instead of

```
when(awsomeService.getOrganisationByShortName("WME")).thenThrow(new AwsomeRuntimeException(ExceptionStatus.NOT_FOUND));
```

Can you try

```
when(awsomeService.getOrganisationByShortName(anyString()).thenThrow(new AwsomeRuntimeException(ExceptionStatus.NOT_FOUND));
```

The line above should fix your mocking behaviour.

Comment: Allass even with the anyString() catch it does not work.

Comment: Afher a bit of more work, it seems jersy is not fully loaded so error messages dont work as the whole bc jersy is not fully loaded in the Container. I am going to try to tes with a difrent container.